# your children’s past will be in part your present

Tags: meaning-in-context

To some degree, we understand, however, that the segregation of our consciousness into present, past, and future is both a fiction and an oddly self-referential framework; your present was part of your mother’s future, and **your children’s past will be in part your present**.
(Source: The Pivotal Generation by Henry Shue)

Q. I am confused about the meaning of the bold part because of 'in part'. If we paraphrase the bold part, which is correct?

1. Part of your children's past will be your present. (=Your present will be part of your children's past)
2. Your children's past will be part of your present.

I thought that there could a possibility that the author is giving an example that expresses 'your present can be a part of your mother's future from a past point of view, and, similarly, your present can be a part of your children's past from a future point of view'. But, I am not sure.

Comment: I suspect meaning 2 was intended, as a not totally successful attempt to say *your children’s past is (was/would become) part of your present* without repeating "part of". I also think "will be" is grammatically wrong here.

Comment: #1 cannot be intended for the math of it. The = sign stands for **be**: Your children’s past = in part your present. So the *in part* would not apply to the children's past.

Comment: I would like to know if "A is in part B = A is part of B" is correct.